# How to Pause Audio onmouseout while image changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an image that when when a user mouse's over the image changes to a new image. Once the new image is clicked, an audio file is played. When the user mouse's out of the image, the image reverts to the default one. The problem is the audio still plays. I'm not that great with js, how do I have the audio pause when the user mouse's out as well? Any helpful feedback is much appreciated. Below is the code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setNewImg() {
        document.getElementById("about-me-img").src = "https://storage.googleapis.com/gd-wagtail-prod-assets/images/evolving_google_identity_2x.max-4000x2000.jpegquality-90.jpg";
    }
    function setOldImg() {
        document.getElementById("about-me-img").src = "imgs/about-me.png";

    }
    function pauseAudio() {
        document.getElementById("about-me-img").pause();
    }
</script>
```

```
<audio id="audio-play">
    <source src="audio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
    </audio>

    <img id="about-me-img" onmouseover="setNewImg()" onmouseout="setOldImg()" onclick="document.getElementById('audio-play').play(); return false;" class="about-me-image about-me-img" src="imgs/about-me.png" alt="" width="200px;">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `pauseAudio` in `setOldImg`, and change `document.getElementById("about-me-img").pause();` to `document.getElementById("audio-play").pause();`

```
function setOldImg() {
    document.getElementById("about-me-img").src = "imgs/about-me.png";
    pauseAudio();

}
function pauseAudio() {
    document.getElementById("audio-play").pause();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Try change "about-me-img" in your paiseAudio() function to "audio-play".

Answer (score 1):

To fix this you simply need to call `pause()` on the `audio` element when the `mouseout` happens on the `img` element.

However you should note that the `onX` event attributes are now very outdated and no longer good practice. You should be attaching your events unobtrusively instead. As such, try this:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let audio = document.querySelector('#audio-play');
  let img = document.querySelector('#about-me-img');

  audio.volume = 0.1; // just for testing, so it doesn't deafen you

  img.addEventListener('mouseover', () => img.src = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/gd-wagtail-prod-assets/images/evolving_google_identity_2x.max-4000x2000.jpegquality-90.jpg');
  img.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
    img.src = 'imgs/about-me.png';
    audio.pause();
  });
  img.addEventListener('click', () => audio.play());
});
```

```css
img {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #C00;
}
```

```html
<audio id="audio-play" controls>
  <source src="http://www.sousound.com/music/healing/healing_01.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>

<img id="about-me-img" class="about-me-image about-me-img" src="imgs/about-me.png" alt="" />
```